# Full width header in jekyll?

Tags: sass, jekyll, github-pages

In my Jekyll site all content has specific width. As I understand this comes from `/css/main.scss` :

```
$content-width:    800px;
$on-palm:          600px;
$on-laptop:        800px;
```

I tried using "local" css in order to overwrite these. And it didn't worked.

Also the above affects the whole content.

Is there any way to make the header (`/_includes/header.html`) full width and keep the rest content with the default-centered width (inherited from above)?

Comment: This doesn't seem specific to jekyll or GitHub pages. It sounds like it's a CSS question. Can you provide a link to the site you're talking about? What exactly do you mean by "using local css"? What exactly do you mean when you say it didn't work?

Comment: Are you use `!important` in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **_includes/header.html**, change `<div class="wrapper">` for `<div class="wrapper-header">`.

In **_sass/base.scss** add :

```
.wrapper-header {
    padding-right: $spacing-unit;
    padding-left: $spacing-unit;
    @extend %clearfix;

    @include media-query($on-laptop) {
        padding-right: $spacing-unit / 2;
        padding-left: $spacing-unit / 2;
    }
}
```