# How can I change the rendered width of a github README.md?

Tags: github, width, markdown, readme

when browsing to https://github.com/timotheecour/D_vs_nim or https://github.com/timotheecour/D_vs_nim/blob/master/README.md I'd like the displayed markdown show up with a custom (larger) width. Is that possible?
If possible the width would depend on browser window size, eg `width=max(browser_width, fixed_width)`.

EDIT: curious whether a PR in https://github.com/github/markup could help to achieve that.

Comment: Ridiculous! On a 2560x1440 monitor, the page is limited to 894px!

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use a dedicated repository, compatible with [GitHub Pages](https://www.google.fr/search?q=github%20pages&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=Pue2WvvlA4T98weOmrDoDQ), in order to be able to generate a markdown file content as you want (with a custom width for instance).
See "[What is GitHub Pages?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/)".

For anything else, like a regular repository, only GitHub is controlling how the markdown pages are rendered.

Comment: How exactly would I modify https://github.com/timotheecour/D_vs_nim/ (in which I enabled github pages) to make the markdown files render at full width? Couldn't find any simple answer on the web. My guess is I'd need to create a custom `assets/css/style.scss` but not clear what property would make the markdown full width

Comment: @timotheecour Are you using Jekyll? (as in https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/)

Comment: yes ; but I just am not sure what to put inside style.scss `Add any custom CSS (or Sass, including imports) you'd like immediately after the @import line.` to achieve the desired effect (so that markdown files are rendered as full width)

Comment: @timotheecour Could you adapt https://stackoverflow.com/a/38713667/6309 to not just the header but the all page?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem for myself by installing chrome extension [widescreen for github](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/widescreen-for-github/elikdceclccjilahimjfceoalhdbndan?hl=en). It requires [stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) (available for other browsers, see https://add0n.com/stylus.html); `stylus` replaces the older `stylish` which was banned on chrome. Of course, it won't solve the problem for others unless they use an extension too. 
For example, this [page](https://github.com/timotheecour/D_vs_nim) has tables that render much better (in full width) using that extension.

My older answer mentioned
https://userstyles.org/styles/108591/github-wide?utm_campaign=stylish_stylepage

Comment: Yes, as you mention, that would only solve the presentation for you. FOr others, see my answer.